# what about errors those appear after updating the android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am using android studio 3.6 canary 5 version with `kotlin programming` language, when I upgraded it, it starts to show errors such like :
I can not use `background attribute` within xml
I can not import icons into my project
I can not import drawable `(MYSTYLES.xml)` files such as `shapes` and `background` files.

in Button xml file :

```
android="@drawable/background_shape"
```

it always shows error that the file is not exists 
(can not resolve symbol @drawable.....)
...>
in kotlin activity

```
setContentView(R.layout.login_layout)
```

it always shows error that the file is not exists 
.
>
when I import icons, it says that the are errors and exceptions

```
android:background="@drawable/background_shape"

setContentView(R.layout.login_layout)
```

Comment: Please try to clean project and then rebuild project!

Comment: If the clean project doesn't work, try to invalidate the cache and restart Android Studio.

Comment: I tried so many times before and it didn't work.